# Calling a separate Java file to open a second gui window

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

I currently have a java file that has buttons to create new GUI windows. I have a second java file that is in the same project that I would like to have open when the user clicks a specific button. The second file has all the components add and just needs to be initiated in my "Main java file" (file one). How can I do this? (calling and calling and instantiating the second java file not making the method).

Any Comments or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this post isn't marked as solved yet, I suppose you haven't found a solution to the problem.
Only 2 things can be wrong here. Either your second class is wrong, or your listener is. All you need to make sure to get your "second frame" to show is to add the setVisible(true), and to create a new object of your second class as stated in previous posts.

This is what your second class needs to create an empty window:

```
public class MySecondClass extend JFrame{

   public MySecondClass(){
        setSize(200, 200);
        setVisible(true);
        //additional calls
     }
}
```

and your listener should be as below in the constructor of your mainclass:

```
theButton.addActionListener(new buttonListener());
```

and last, add the following as a inner class in your mainclass:

```
public class buttonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                new MySecondClass();
          }
}
```

if you still can't get your code to work, add a printline in the constructor of your second class, and one in your listener class so you can figure out which part is faulty

Comment: @Johnston why was this marked as the answer? It seems like rosh provided the same information except much earlier. Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I don't know if I understand correctly, but you want create windows when clicking on a button?

Try this:

```
new GUIConstructorNameHere.setVisible(true);
```

PS: The GUIConstructorName is the constructor method of the class that you want to show.

Comment: well i want to create a new window and call the second java class file that has all the componets already set up

Answer (score 1):

You should create a method for the same, say you have two files, eg. file1 & file2
You have to navigate from file1 to file2 on click of a button in file1.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
file2 f2 = new file2();
this.dispose(); //closes current file
f1.seVisible(true); //opens the next file
}
```

Comment: do i add the path to the file in the "new file2()" backets? Also i do not initiate the gui in the second file so i have to do that before i do a setVisible - thanks for your answer

Comment: You do not need to add path in the "new file2()" brackets, & I do not think we need to initiate the GUI in the second, the "file2 f2 = new file2();" initiates it & "f1.seVisible(true);" just makes it visible :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give enough information. Java has more than one GUI library, Swing and SWT being the ones that come immediately to mind. If you're using Swing and your "second class file" that you want to show extends JPanel, then you can create a new YourSecondClass() and add it to your JFrame. In Swing all components must be added to a Container, so your second class must either BE the container (e.g. JPanel), or the components in your second class can be added to an existing container.

Comment: Also, I should not that in order to instantiate a new YourSecondClass() you're going to need to understand import statements, google it. (Or explain more in depth what it is you need to do... I don't want to explain things that aren't helpful to you)

Comment: sorry for not specifying -- im using Swing - it completely slipped my mind

Comment: @Johnston Not a problem. So does your second class extend JPanel? If not, can you show the relevant code from the second class? In general, anything that is a Component such as a JButton, text fields, etc can be added to a JPanel or JFrame because those are both containers. Therefore (if your second class doesn't extend JPanel) you should instantiate a urObj = new YourSecondClass() and do yourNewJpanel.Add(urObj.textField), etc.

Comment: Both my files extend JFrame. Also i tried instatiating my file doing a file2 window = new file2(); (file2 being my other file in the project) As i mentioned before im not tring to add those componets into my current window but to open a new window and add the componets in that class

Comment: @johnston Then it would seem that (as other posters have answered) creating a urObj= new YourSecondClass() and then urObj.setVisible(true) should do the trick. You do need to import your class before that will work, however. Also, just a side note, please refer to [what you're calling a file] as a class.